# Split json into separate schema and data units

Tags: python, json, compression, schema

I want to split a json object into two separate units

- one holding the schema
- one holding the data or values (in binary compressed format).

**Edit - Why**

I have a web app with a json api. I want footprint like protobuf, but seamlessness like json. I think all info regarding the object needed for like protobuf or anything else, is already in the json object.

Therefore I want to run-time generate the schema and the data and send only the tuple

```
(schema_hash, binary_compressed)
```

to the server. If the server recognizes the schema_hash it can convert the tuple into internal object and work on it. Otherwise the sender can just resend the json and the server will create the schema and cache it. Hence you get protobuf speed and json ease.

It has to work for all json object not only flat like below.

**Example**

```json
{
    "variable_a": 1,
    "variable_b": 2
}
```

**Using python [genson](https://github.com/wolverdude/GenSON) I can generate:**

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "variable_a": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "variable_b": {
        "type": "integer"
    }
},
"required": [
    "variable_a",
    "variable_b"
]
```

**How to generate the data part**

Which in this case should only be two integers taking up 2*32 bits of space in total

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick?

```
obj = {
    "variable_a": 1,
    "variable_b": 2
}
# Get the values in the dictionary
vals = obj.values()
# Store the values as bytes
vals_as_bytes = bytearray(vals)
# Write the bytes to a binary file
with open("filename", "wb") as file:
    file.write(vals_as_bytes)
```

Comment: Yes, that would work for the flat json in my example but I not for nested json. It is also not precisely clear how to deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the json as Dictionary. to iterating over it you can use this:

```
dic  = {
    "variable_a": 1,
    "variable_b": 2
}
```

for iterating over it use the code like this:

```
for key in dic:
    print(key, '-->', dic[key])
```

However if you have multiple data records as json you may save it in a dataframe object provided that attributes are the same in all json objects:

```
columns = []
for key in dic:
    columns.append(key)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

df.loc[len(df)]  = dic
```

Comment: Thats a creative solution, but I want the solution to work for stand alone nested json. Not only multiple records flat json compression.